# PySimpleGui - window size doesnt autofit dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I'm trying to auto resize a PySimpleGUI window.

consider the following:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

CommandWindow = sg.Multiline(size=(80,20),echo_stdout_stderr=True,key=OUTPUT_KEY,visible=False)

window = sg.Window("FOO", layout=[CommandWindow],element_justification='center')
```

when the event is triggered, a sg.Multiline element's visible trait is updated to True.

then I refresh the window and it resizes (expands) to fit the element shown inside.

when I change the visible trait to False again, the window maintain its size and doesnt shrink back.

the execution as follows:

```py
window[OUTPUT_KEY].update(visible=True/False)
window.refresh()
```

Comment: Search for "shrink" the call reference documentation.

Comment: didnt find anything related in docs :-/

Comment: Really.... on this page... the "Call Reference" documentation, you don't find the word "shrink"? https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#layout-helper-funcs ... huh... sorry for the suggestion.

Comment: To be clear... It IS a good question... 

Answer (score 0):

I think this will perhaps be the best answer I can come up with since StackOverflow answers do not age well, especially for the PySimpleGUI project which is ever-evolving.

The Demo Browser utility is made specifically to help answer questions like this.  Of course, the documentation should also be used (PySimpleGUI.org).

The Demo Programs serve many purposes.  One is to show specific techniques.  The Demo Browser is a way for you to quickly and easily search, edit, and execute this code.

The attached screenshot is what I see when searching for "shrink" using this tool (as of Aug 2022...).   The first item answers this specific issue.  Maybe I got lucky?  "I would rather be lucky than good".  The docs and tools provided with PySimpleGUI are the best place to turn for questions rather than SO.  They'll be the most accurate, the most up to date, and are part of the project itself.

Good lucky Jedi!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what solved it for me, Thanks to @Mike from PSG,
is using:

```py
 sg.Pin(,shrink=True)
```

as shown in docs: https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#layout-helper-funcs

Comment: The default is True for the shrink parm. All you need to do is "pin" the element.  Also, be sure to use lower case for `pin`.  It's a "helper function", not an "object"